# Secure way to manage mysql through web browser

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I would like to offer clients access to their own mySQL database. Is there a secure way of doing this?

Is there any way to secure phpmyadmin without using a htaccess password or restricting it to trusted users?

Or if the answer to this is 'no', is there any software that is perhaps more simple than phpmyadmin but more secure?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: phpmyadmin supports [SSL certifcates](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssl-certificates-with-phpmyadmin-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps).

Comment: What aspect of the security of phpmyadmin are you concerned with? IIRC phpmyadmin requires the user to provide their MySQL credentials. So as long as you've set those up properly, they'll only have access to their database anyway

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - I think the user is more concerned of, viewing said data he has the right to access, but said data leaking because the connection isn't secure.

Comment: Well, HTTPS doesn’t really protect against bugs. Unless client certificates are used, but that’s generally too complicated.

Comment: @Questioner why do you perceive phpMyAdmin to be insecure? It has username/password authentication and your vague statement makes everyone guess which answer to give. IMHO this leads to discussion about the insecurities of webapps in general.

Comment: I have no serious concerns over security, just that every phpmyadmin security tutorial I have read seems to state that restricting users by ip is a necessity. Apologies, I should have been more clear.

Comment: @Tom restricting by IP is kind of obsolete concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a secure website using SSL certificate.
2. Create a directory for every customer using a random name.
3. Setup a phpMyAdmin inside every directory.
4. Fix every phpMyAdmin for accesing a single database.
5. Configure phpMyAdmin for asking MySQL credentials.
6. Add HTTP user/password to every directory (optional)
7. Restrict access to every/some directories by IP (if possible)

I think going beyond step 5 is a total waste of time, but that would certainly improve security.

Comment: Step 6 would definitely avoid a lot of common security issues with phpMyAdmin, but would be detrimental to the user experience.

Comment: Maybe the user can choose saving the password in the web browser.